# SQL Select where exclusive Or /Case

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need a query based on an exclusive Or statement for this I try using the case but I won't get a result in case of Null...

```
...
and b.[U_Periode] = CASE
                        when (b.U_Periode= @period) then @period
                        when (b.U_Periode is NULL ) then null
                    end 
...
```

The Case that won't be catched is... if B.U_Status is null and b.U_Periode is null.
If the var Periode match the Value and the U_Status = 0 or 1

the only way getting this working for me was this:

```
...
and
ISNULL( b.[U_Status],'0') = CASE 
                    when (b.U_Status= '1') then '1'
                    when (isnull( b.U_Status,'0')= '0') then '0'

                end 
and 

ISNULL (b.[U_Periode],'01.01.1901') = CASE
                    when (b.U_Periode= @period) then @period
                    when (ISNULL (b.U_Periode,'01.01.1901') = '01.01.1901' ) then '01.01.1901'
                end
```

are there any other better solutions for this?
Best regards
Oliver

---

Okay... here is my Problem

Table1
InsID   ContractID
1       1
2       1
Table2

```
ID  insid   Period      Status  Count
1   1       null        null    100
2   1       30.09.2015  1       500

3   2       null        null    100
4   2       30.09.2015  1       500

Case '31.08.2015'

in total Value should be 200

in case of '30.09.2015'

the Value should be 1.000

XOR /OR will do the same in this case.

Value case '31.08.2015' = 200
value Case ' 30.09.2015 = 2200
```

So this is somesing like a subquery

```
left join (
        [dbo].[Table2]b 
        inner join [dbo].[Table 3]K on k.DocEntry = b.DocEntry and CAST( k.U_CSetID as int) >0 
        )
 on b.[U_InsID] in(select... but here I should have an if statement...
```

1. If there are results matching the Date join this
2. If not than join the result NULL is matching to periode...

Comment: pls explane better your where case. i dont understand

Comment: Okay. I test the last again and this is like a normal OR... and this is as well the wrong result. I need a Exclusive one. Either the result should based on a real date, if not then it should take the Null....I will post the complete query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olay here is my funktion that chek either a Date Result is there or not.

The only thing is, that the performance is not the best if I run hundreths of sentences ... foreach record (up to app. 1000) I need to query each subtable... and there are many many records in...

Anyway this is the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetInsCounters(@InsId as Varchar(30), @Date as datetime)

returns datetime
as
begin
declare @count as int = 0
declare @Retruns as Datetime
set @count =
            (
                select count( b.Docentry) 
                from [dbo].[Table2]b 
                where b.U_Insid =@InsID 
                and b.U_Status <> '2'
                and b.[U_ObjectType]in ('5','1')
                and b.U_Periode=@Date
            )

if(@count>0)
    begin


        set @Retruns = @date
        end
    else
        begin
         set @Retruns = '01.01.1901'
    end
    return @Retruns
end
```

if anyone gets a better idea???
Best regards
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

you must use the "^" operand, this is XOR operand in TSQL

```
expression ^ expression
```

the expression must return or 0 or 1...

stupid example:

```
WHERE (name like "stackoverflow") ^ (age > 10)
```

font: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277(v=sql.105).aspx

Update for your check

**`WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.[U_Periode], 104) = '30.08.2015') != (a.U_Periode IS NULL)`**

Comment: something like this ... where
(a.[U_Periode] = '30.08.2015')^( a.U_Periode is null) won't work...

Comment: i link you MSDN sql2008-r2 guide, and you say i guess dont work... pls sql version 105 is your version...i think a.[U_Periode] = '30.08.2015' is wrong

Comment: U_Periode what type is?

Comment: WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.[U_Periode], 104) = '30.08.2015') ^ (a.U_Periode IS NULL) -> wrong syntax in the near of ' ^ '

Comment: this is the version 10.50.1600.1

Comment: same for this one WHERE (a.U_Status <>2)^(a.U_status is null) wrong syntax in the near of ' ^ '

Comment: "!=" is <> in 2008 but it is the same wrong systax in the near of " < " ... WHERE (a.U_Status <>2) <> (a.U_status is null)

Comment: when is true this where for you? when is null or a vlue<>2? right?

Comment: not at all... and this could be my Problem.... and i guess i have to use a funktion for this...    I post this into an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. here is the complete query

the Table2 with the Date of 31.08.2015 should have one Record that include 
B_STATUS = Null and B.Preiode = null and there is no available record with the U_Periode '31.08.2015' and a Staus ...

with a date of 30.09.2015
there is a Record matching U_Period = '30.09.2015' in this case the Record with U_Period=null should not effect the result...

```
Declare @period as varchar(20)= '31-08-2015 00:00:00'
declare @Customer as Varchar(15)='12345'
declare @Contract as varchar(30) = '123'
declare @test as varchar(1) =  null


select SUM(cast(K.U_Count as decimal))as counter, K.U_CounterTyp
from [dbo].[Table1] a
left join (
        [dbo].[Table2]b 
        inner join [dbo].[Table 3]K on k.DocEntry = b.DocEntry and CAST( k.U_CSetID as int) >0 
        )
 on b.[U_InsID]=a.[insID] and b.[U_ObjectType]in ('5','1') and 
 ISNULL( b.[U_Status],'0') = CASE 
                    when (b.U_Status= '1') then '1'
                    when (isnull( b.U_Status,'0')= '0') then '0'

                end 
and 

ISNULL (b.[U_Periode],'01.01.1901') = CASE
                    when (b.U_Periode= @period) then @period
                    when (ISNULL (b.U_Periode,'01.01.1901') = '01.01.1901' ) then '01.01.1901'
                end 

where a.[customer] =@Customer and a.[Status]='A' and a.[U_ContrCount]='1'
and a.[manufSN]  in( 
select c.[ManufSN] from [dbo].[Table4] c 
inner join [dbo].[OCTR]d on d.[ContractID] = c.[ContractID]
where c.[ManufSN]=a.[manufSN] 
and d.[CstmrCode] = a.[customer] and d.[ContractID]=@Contract
)
group by K.U_CounterTyp
```